SQLite: update multiple rows on one table based on multiple rows of another
I have 2 cross-referenced tables, called 'scenes' and 'files':
SCENES
  id   created_at   updated_at   scene_id    
  --   -----------  ----------   ----------  
  1    2024-02-13   2024-03-05   vt-1105     
  2    2024-02-14   2024-03-06   KA-338      
  3    2024-02-15   2024-03-07   JU-182      
  4    2024-02-16   2024-03-08   PX-118      
  5    2024-02-17   2024-03-09   po-6339085  
  6    2024-02-18   2024-03-10   la-426    

FILES
  id   created_at   updated_at   filename              scene_id  
  --   -----------  ----------   -------------------   --------  
  1    2024-03-03   2024-03-06   KA-338-A_180_LR.mp4   2         
  2    2024-03-03   2024-03-06   KA-338-B_180_LR.mp4   2         
  3    2024-03-03   2024-03-06   KA-338-C_180_LR.mp4   2         
  4    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-A_180_LR.mp4   3         
  5    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-B_180_LR.mp4   3         
  6    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-C_180_LR.mp4   3         
  7    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-D_180_LR.mp4   3         
  8    2024-03-05   2024-03-07   PX-118-A_180_LR.mp4   4         
  9    2024-03-05   2024-03-07   PX-118-B_180_LR.mp4   4         

I'd like to take scene 'JU-182' (for example) that has 4 video files linked to it (with 'scene_id' = 3 in the 'files' table), and create 4 new duplicate scenes linked to each individual video.  I'm trying to do this in pure SQLite.
So I'd be adding 4 duplicated rows to the 'scenes' table...
SCENES
  id   created_at   updated_at   scene_id    
  --   -----------  ----------   ----------  
  1    2024-02-13   2024-03-05   vt-1105     
  2    2024-02-14   2024-03-06   KA-338      
  3    2024-02-15   2024-03-07   JU-182      
  4    2024-02-16   2024-03-08   PX-118      
  5    2024-02-17   2024-03-09   po-6339085  
  6    2024-02-18   2024-03-10   la-426      
  7    2024-02-15   2024-03-07   JU-182      
  8    2024-02-15   2024-03-07   JU-182      
  9    2024-02-15   2024-03-07   JU-182      
  10   2024-02-15   2024-03-07   JU-182      

...and updating the 'files' table so all the rows with the 'scene_id' of '3' (rows 4,5,6,7) change to 7,8,9,10 (the IDs of the newly created scenes):
FILES
  id   created_at   updated_at   filename              scene_id  
  --   -----------  ----------   -------------------   --------  
  1    2024-03-03   2024-03-06   KA-338-A_180_LR.mp4   2         
  2    2024-03-03   2024-03-06   KA-338-B_180_LR.mp4   2         
  3    2024-03-03   2024-03-06   KA-338-C_180_LR.mp4   2         
  4    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-A_180_LR.mp4   7         
  5    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-B_180_LR.mp4   8         
  6    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-C_180_LR.mp4   9         
  7    2024-03-04   2024-03-07   JU-182-D_180_LR.mp4   10        
  8    2024-03-05   2024-03-07   PX-118-A_180_LR.mp4   4         
  9    2024-03-05   2024-03-07   PX-118-B_180_LR.mp4   4         

I'm attempting to make this happen using the scene ID only, so I've stored values in a temporary table called 'variables' like so:
CREATE TEMP TABLE variables (
    scene_id TEXT,
    scene_index INT,
    files_total INT,
    file_ids TEXT
);
INSERT INTO variables VALUES (
    'JUVR-182', -- manually change to internal scene ID
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
); 
UPDATE variables
    SET scene_index = (
    SELECT id FROM scenes WHERE scene_id = (
            SELECT scene_id FROM variables
        )
    );  
UPDATE variables
    SET files_total = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM files WHERE scene_id = (
            SELECT scene_index FROM variables
        )
    );
UPDATE variables
    SET file_ids = (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id, ',') FROM files WHERE scene_id = (
            SELECT scene_index FROM variables
        )
    );

VARIABLES
  scene_id   scene_index   scene_newIDs   files_total   file_ids  
  --------   -----------   ------------   -----------   --------  
  JU-182     3             null           4             4,5,6,7   

..then duplicated the rows this way:
WITH cte(x) AS (
    SELECT 1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT x + 1 
    FROM cte WHERE x < (SELECT files_total FROM variables)
)
INSERT INTO scenes (created_at, updated_at, scene_id)
    SELECT created_at, updated_at, scene_id
    FROM scenes JOIN cte
    WHERE id = (SELECT scene_index FROM variables);

...and I'm a bit stuck here.  I've stored the new scene ids in my variables table first:
VARIABLES
  scene_id   scene_index   scene_newIDs   files_total   file_ids  
  --------   -----------   ------------   -----------   --------  
  JU-182     3             7,8,9,10       4             4,5,6,7   

Not sure I'm going about this the right way, but how to make rows 4,5,6,7 on the 'files' table update to the values 7,8,9,10?

Ok. This is strange. Do you realize you now have a scene record (#3) with no corresponding file records?

Its nice and compact to display what is happening via your variables table using comma separated values. The problem is it adds an extra step when it comes to using those values. You are better off creating 4 variable records with 1 ID change each.

Yes, I'm trying to split the scene up, so I'd probably erase the original scene on #3...so not a problem there's no corresponding file anymore.

So add rows the Variables table instead of putting an 'array' in a single cell?

Yes, otherwise you will need to use the split function to get them into rows you can easily work with.

OK, maybe I'd need an additional table to store those 2 arrays as 2 columns...

I'm interested in your ideas.  I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm struggling through how to do things.

I thought SQLite didn't have variables?

You are correct. SQLite doesn't have variables. You will need to work with the 1 variable table you got.

So if I have a table: id (1,2,3,4) scene_id (7,8,9,10) file_id (4,5,6,7), how would I run through it to update the files table? (Sorry, I can't draw a proper table in these replies)

See example.  The approach to the task is somewhat different from your.

Insert into Scenes

insert into scenes (created_at,updated_at,scene_id)
select created_at,updated_at,scene_code 
from(
select s.created_at,s.updated_at,s.scene_id as scene_code -- upd1
  ,count(*)over(partition by s.scene_id) cnt
from files f
left join scenes s on s.id=f.scene_id
) x
where cnt>1

2.Update scene_id in table Files to new id's
update files
   set  scene_id=new_scene_id
from  (
   select file_id, created_at,updated_at,scene_code 
       ,scene_id,old_scene_id,new_scene_id,srn,frn
   from(
     select *,s.scene_id as scene_code,f.scene_id old_scene_id
        ,s.id new_scene_id,f.id file_id
     from (select f0.*,s0.scene_id main_scene 
             ,row_number()over(partition by f0.scene_id order by f0.id) frn
           from files f0 left join scenes s0 on f0.scene_id=s0.id
     ) f
    left join (
      select * 
        ,row_number()over(partition by s1.scene_id order by s1.id) srn
      from scenes s1
     ) s on s.scene_id=f.main_scene  and (s.srn-1)=f.frn
 ) x
)y
where y.file_id=files.id  and y.srn>1 -- upd2

Example fiddle
Update 1. in first part columns created_at and updated_at can be taken from scenes.
Update2. for scene with single video file, additional rows in scenes file not inserted, and new scene_id not updated.

Thanks, you're the master!  It's going to take me a few days as a beginner to follow what you've done here step by step.  Looks very efficient.

What I didn't include above is that most scenes have a single video file linked to them in the files table, and I don't want those altered.  With this code those get replaced with "null".  https://dbfiddle.uk/r0HCZ7ZU?hide=864

Add condition  (https://dbfiddle.uk/giWKlJ3b?hide=864)  where y.file_id=files.id and y.srn>1 for rows, where single video file linked to exclude them from update. In first part, no row added for single video file - so ``null` is expected.

You've been an amazing help, ValNik.  One last thing I'm trying to do: I also want to append the names of the split scenes to -A, -B, -C, etc so that they have unique scene identifiers.  Any scenes originally with 1 associated file should be left alone.  As I've been going through your code and trying to understand it, I've started working on it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/OYpou8dR?hide=3472

I don't know what you need it for. Anyway, that's what I would do CHAR(64 + row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id order by s.id)) as part_id

I probably didn't explain well.  When I split 'JU-182' into 4 new scenes, with your current code I get the names ('JU-182', 'JU-182', 'JU-182', 'JU-182'), but I want the new scenes to be named ('JU-182-A', 'JU-182-B', 'JU-182-C', 'JU-182-D').  A scene like 'VT-1105' would not be split so the name should not be altered.

Maybe this step needs to be done at the very end?  I'm still working my way through your code to understand where it's best to place.

perhaps, indeed, it will be better at later stages. Otherwise, you will lose connection with the old scene, or this link will need to be  processed as old_scene_id=left(scene_id,length(scene_id)-2) 'Scene123'=left('Scene123-A',10-2)

I'm updating this post to include a variation on ValNik's answer that's a bit easier for me as a beginner to read:
/*-----------------------------------------
split multi-file scenes to single file scenes
----------------------------------------*/

INSERT INTO scenes (created_at, updated_at, scene_id)
   SELECT created_at, updated_at, base_id
   FROM (
      SELECT *, 
         s.scene_id AS base_id,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id) AS files_tally
      FROM files f LEFT JOIN scenes s
         ON f.scene_id = s.id
         ORDER BY f.id ASC
   )
   WHERE files_tally > 1

/*------------------------------------------------------
re-assign files to new duplicate scenes in files table
------------------------------------------------------*/

UPDATE files

   SET scene_id = new_scene_id

FROM (

   SELECT

      file_id, 
      created_at,
      updated_at,
      base_id,
      scene_id,
      old_scene_id,
      new_scene_id,
      s_file_no,
      f_file_no

   FROM (

      SELECT

        *,
        f.id AS file_id,
        s.scene_id AS base_id, 
        f.scene_id AS old_scene_id, 
        s.id AS new_scene_id

      FROM (
  
        -- files table: assign value to file parts
        SELECT f1.*,
           s1.scene_id AS base_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f1.scene_id) AS f_file_no
        FROM files f1 LEFT JOIN scenes s1
        ON f1.scene_id = s1.id
  
      ) f LEFT JOIN (
  
        -- scenes table: assign value to file parts
        SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s2.scene_id) AS s_file_no
        FROM scenes s2
        ORDER BY s2.id ASC
  
      ) s

      ON s.scene_id = f.base_id AND (s.s_file_no - 1)  = f.f_file_no

   )

) f3

WHERE f3.file_id = files.id AND f3.s_file_no > 1


This then gives the duplicate scenes unique ID names:
/*------------------------------------------------------
append suffixes to duplicate IDs in scenes table
------------------------------------------------------*/

UPDATE scenes
  SET scene_id = new_scene_id
FROM (
    SELECT 
      s.id AS id,
      CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id) 
        WHEN 1 THEN s.scene_id 
        ELSE s.scene_id || '-' || CHAR(
          64 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.scene_id)-1
        )
      END as new_scene_id
    FROM scenes s
    ORDER BY s.id ASC
) s2
WHERE s2.id = scenes.id

id  created_at  updated_at  scene_id
--  ----------  ----------  ---------
1   2024-02-13  2024-03-05  VT-1105
2   2024-02-14  2024-03-06  KA-338
3   2024-02-15  2024-03-07  JU-182
4   2024-02-16  2024-03-08  PX-118
5   2024-02-17  2024-03-09  PO-6339085
6   2024-02-18  2024-03-10  LA-426
7   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338-A
8   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338-B
9   2024-03-03  2024-03-06  KA-338-C
10  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-A
11  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-B
12  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-C
13  2024-03-04  2024-03-07  JU-182-D
14  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118-A
15  2024-03-05  2024-03-07  PX-118-B

